# Android studio: Resetting for cold boot, emulation engine failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Due to school curiculum, i began working with android studio today. The exercises were simple, make an app and run it in a few different AVDs. Initially this **worked**. The app ran fine on the pre-configured AVD (and this wasn't any complicated app, just some text on the screen), but then when i tried to create my own AVDs it started giving the following error: Resetting for cold boot, emulation engine failed. I believed this happened because i created the AVD wrong, but when i tried to test it on the pre configured one again, it also failed in the same fashion. I have tried the following:

1. Cold boot the device from the manager. It immediately crashes.
2. Wipe data (even though there should be none). Does nothing.
3. Delete all the devices and remake them.
4. Install Intel HAXM. Changes nothing.
5. Reinstalling android studio. Still brings up the same issue.
6. Going a bit deeper, i manually deleted everything, android studio, it's configuration and the SDK, so i started from scratch. Issue still persists.

I could barely find any info on this error with Google, except a thread on this site, which mainly features solutions i have already tried. I have no idea what could be the cause, and nay help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!